# How to remove an entire word in a sentence c++

Tags: c++

I want to remove specific word in a sentences and I have tried to breakdown the sentences into word and compare the word but when i call the erase function , the index will update. I have tried another method while it will delete substring in a word which i dont want to. Can anyone help me out a bit? what approach i should use.

**input**

> The house whirled around two or three times and rose slowly through the air.

**output**

> The house whirled around two or three times and rose slowly through  air.

here is my prototype of the function

```
int RemoveWordFromLine(string line, string word)
{
  // ==========================
  string tmp_str="",spacebar=" ";
  int start=0,end=-1;
  for(int i=0;i<line.length();i++)
  {

    if(isspace(line[i])||int(line[i])==44||int(line[i])==46)
    {
      cout<<tmp_str<<" "<<start<<" "<<end<<endl; // compare
      if(tmp_str==word)
      {
        line.erase(start,end);  
      }
      tmp_str="";
      start=i+1;
      end=i;

    } else
    {
      tmp_str+=line[i];
      end++;

    }

  }
    if(tmp_str==word)
      {
        line.erase(start,end);  
      }
    cout<<tmp_str<<" "<<start<<" "<<end<<endl; // compare
    cout<<line<<endl;


  // ==========================
}
```

[ideone's link](https://ideone.com/oWzxTC)

Comment: One way is to note down the indices to be erased, and then erase them after the loop

Comment: Or break the source string in a vector of strings, and then use the erase/remove idiom

Comment: can i use array to store the indices? ........that is hard in somehow

Comment: You tell me. If you store the start index of the word to be erased, won't you also need the end index of the word so that you know when it is done?

Comment: [OT]: avoid magic numbers `44`, `46`, use `'.'`, `','` instead.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted in your question? When I run the function with
    RemoveWordFromLine( "The house whirled around two or three times and rose slowly through the air.", "the") I get The house whirled around two or three times and rose slowly through air as output.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your function in the following way:

```
void RemoveWordFromLine(std::string &line, const std::string &word)
{
  auto n = line.find(word);
  if (n != std::string::npos)
  {
    line.erase(n, word.length());
  }
}
```

And use it like:

```
std::string line("This is a wrong line");
RemoveWordFromLine(line, "wrong");
printf("line is: '%s'\n", line.c_str());
```

Prints out:

> line is: 'This is a  line'

Comment: Care with sub word, unsure OP wants to transform `"then we go"` to `"n we go"`;
and possibly in a loop to remove all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing end position instead of length of string to be deleted.
You just need to replace

```
 if(tmp_str==word)
      {
        line.erase(start,end);  
      }
```

with

```
 if(tmp_str==word)
      {
        line.erase(start,word.length()+1);  //+1 to prevent 2 spaces
      }
```

You could also do `line.erase(start-1,word.length()+1);` if you would like to keep '.' or ',' after deleted word.

Answer (score 0):

With [`<regex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), you might do:

```
std::string RemoveWordFromLine(const std::string& line, std::string word)
{
    // \s* : extra optional spaces at the start
    // \b : word boundary
    // Ideally, we should check that `word` doesn't break regex too:
    std::regex reg("\\s*\\b" + word + "\\b");
    return std::regex_replace(line, reg, "");
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c7d1f272b823b0d)

Answer (score -1):

Remove multiple occurrences as well with this function

```
 void removeWords(string& s, const string& p) {
    size_t n = p.length();
    for (size_t i = s.find(p);
        i != string::npos;
        i = s.find(p))
        // take care of subword 
                if((i==0 && (i+n <= s.length()) && (s[i+n+1] == ' ' || s[i+ n+1] == '.'))||   //first word
       (i + n <= s.length() && s[i - 1] == ' ' && (s[i+n]=='\0' ||s[i + n] == '.' || s[i+ n+1] == ' '))) //other word

          s.erase(i, n);
}
```

Comment: You remove *"sub-word"* too.